# Typescript - How to set the value of an object key in a Map

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary, set, key

I have a Map which takes a Lecture as Key and an Array of Todos as value.

```js
lecturesWithTodos: Map<Lecture, Todos[]> = new Map<Lecture, Todos[]>();
```

Now I first set the key of this Map without any value (because I get the Todos later).

```js
student.semester.lectures.forEach((lecture) => {
    this.lecturesWithTodos.set(lecture, []);
});
```

Now I just would like to set my Todos to its specific Key.

```js
todos.forEach((todo) => {
   this.lecturesWithTodos.get(lecture).push(todo);
});
```

But at this point it is always saying "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".
I know I can get it done, when I am using a string as Key, but I would like to use my Object instead, because it makes things easier for me later.

Is there a way how to get the get-Method working on this lecture object?

Comment: How does it *"make things easier later on"*? You would face the exact problem again while trying to retrieve data from the map

Comment: make sure you're using the same lecture reference that was added in the first `forEach`

Comment: Because when i iterate over that map I can get the values of my lecture object directly without the need of an extra lectures array. 
I checked a thousand times they are identically but the get-Method seems to not recognize it

Comment: Yes that is cause although the properties are same they are different objects, so `.get(..)` will not consider them to be equal.

Comment: is there another way how i can set the value of this object key?

Comment: AFAIK, it would complicate things further as you would then need to check if each key has the "equal properties" and then for that key push Todos.

Comment: So storing the key as strings or numbers and making a separate lecture array is the only practical way?

Comment: Seems like, retrieving values from the map would be mush easier that way. Curious as to why you want to store the key as an object - how will you retrieve the values from it? Won't you face this issue all over again

Comment: Because later I just need to iterate over the whole Map, get every key/value pair and do sth. with it. And if I already got the key as Lecture and not as string, I would not need to some extra stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it would be difficult to retrieve elements from the map later on, one way to achieve your objective is illustrated below.

---

Assuming that your types are as follows (change them as per your requirement)

```
interface Todos {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

interface Lecture {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

The given data:

```
 lectures: Lecture[] = [
    { id: 100, name: 'ENG' },
    { id: 200, name: 'PHY' },
    { id: 300, name: 'BIO' }
  ];

  todos: Todos[] = [
    { id: 100, name: 'Add' },
    { id: 100, name: 'Sub' },
    { id: 300, name: 'Mul' }
  ];
```

Logic to create the map

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.lectures.forEach(lecture => {
      this.lecturesWithTodos.set(lecture, []);
   });

   this.todos.forEach(todo => {
      const findLecture = this.findById(todo.id);
      const findAllTodos = this.findTodos(todo.id);

      if (findLecture && findAllTodos) {
        // implies that there is a previous todo added earlier
        this.lecturesWithTodos.set(findLecture, [...findAllTodos, todo]);
      } else if (findLecture) {
        // implies that its a new todo being set
        this.lecturesWithTodos.set(findLecture, [todo]);
      }
  });

}

/** Used to find Lecture based on todo id **/
findById(id: number) {
    return Array.from(this.lecturesWithTodos.keys()).find(e => e.id === id);
}

/** Used to find all previous todos based on todo id **/
findTodos(id: number) {
    // todos is a 2D array
    let todos = Array.from(this.lecturesWithTodos.values());

    // convert to 1D array for finding values from it
    return [].concat.apply([], todos).filter(e => e.id === id);
}
```